# Autoplay background video on android and iOS

Tags: html, css, video, autoplay

This article - https://blog.synq.fm/html5-video-looping-autoplay-on-ios-and-android - says it's enough to add `"autoplay muted loop playsinline"` to a video for it to correctly autoplay on mobile devices, but it doesn't work. An example - http://michaelmedvedskiy.website/

Which has the code

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="myVideo" >
```

Is there a concistent way to make muted autoplay work through out the devices?

Comment: Do you have "Low Power Mode" enabled? in that case, just try disabling it.

Comment: Tried it just now, didn't work.

Comment: Does it work in your case? (on your mobile device)

Comment: The link you provided does not appear to have the muted and plays inline attributes - this is how it looked when I checked just now: <video muted="" id="myVideo">
  <source src="media/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: This has been corrected as I've tried to cheat my way out of it by writing a js script to play the video on load, which didn't work either. The one with these tags is not the way to make my android chrome autorun the vid

Answer (score 3):

I had tried the following line:

`<video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="myVideo" >`

It did not work for me either.

Then I did the below and it worked and I have no idea why this made a difference, but it did.

```
<video  width="100%" allowfullscreen="true" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline="playsinline" loop="loop">
  <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution for more than 2 hours and your answer solved my problem. Thank you! You saved my life!

Answer (score 0):

I did the below and it worked and I have no idea why this made a difference, but it did.

```
muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline="playsinline" loop="loop"
```